# python - How to replace an int output with a string output?

Tags: python

```
a=1

while a<=100:
    if a % 3 == 0:
         print("foo")
    elif a % 5 == 0:
         print("bar")

    print(a)

    a=a+1
```

My output would print:

```
 1
 2
 foo
 3
 4
 bar
 5
 6
```

Instead of the output to be number 3, it should display the string (replace it)

how could I code a command that will replace the int with a string?

Comment: `else` is your friend

Comment: You do realize that multiples of both 3 and 5 will only print foo. Is that what you intend?

Comment: (`for a in range(1,101)` could be your friend too. Or `for a in range(1, 101, 5)`)

Comment: Why are you not using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `else` clause:

```
a=1

while a<=100:
    if a % 3 == 0:
         print("foo")

    elif a % 5 == 0:
         print("bar")

    else:
        print(a)

    a=a+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a =list(range(1,101))

for i in a :

if i % 3 and i % 5 == 0:
  print(foobar)
elif i % 3 == 0 :
  print(foo)
elif i % 5 == 0 :
  print(bar)
else:
  print(i)
```